# Having trouble Implementing Add/Get in my LinkedList - Java

Tags: java

I have something wrong with my code, and I always keep on getting null pointer... I am trying to make my own linkedlist with an add and get function.

Here is the code I have right now:

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
private class ListNode<E> {
    public E data;
    public ListNode<E> next;
}

private ListNode<E> head;
private int size;

public LinkedList() {       
    size = 0;
}

public int size() {
    return size;
}
public void add(E e) {
    if(size == 0){ // first node in the list

        ListNode<E> firstNode = new ListNode<E>();
        firstNode.data = e;
        firstNode.next = null;

        size++; //increment size counter 
        // set this node equal to first node in the linked list
        this.head = firstNode;

    }
    else{ // not the first node
        ListNode<E> temp = head;
        while(temp != null){ // find the last node
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        // create new node to be added to linked list
        ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>();
        newNode.data = e;
        newNode.next = null;

        // set the previous last node to the new, created node
        temp = newNode;

        size++; //increment size of the LinkedList
    }
}
public E get(int index) {
    if( index > size){ // account for if user inputs something that is reachable within LinkedList
        return null;
    }
    ListNode<E> temp = head;
    if(index == 0){
        return head.data;
    }
    else{
        for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return temp.data;
    }

    }
```

Now in my main I add a LinkedList of integers called num and add numbers 0-9 into it. Now when I use the function System.out.println(num.get(1)); I get the nullExceptionError that highlights my get function's return temp.data;

I think it has to do something with my adding, or somewhere along the lines of not pointing my nodes correctly...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are updating the `next` reference properly within the Nodes in your list.

When you add a new element, your goal is to set the `next` field of the last `ListNode` in your linkedList to be equal to a new `ListNode` object with a specific data field.

However, you attempt to add a new node with the following line:

```
temp = newNode;
```

Since temp is a local variable the above line does **nothing** but update the value of `temp` locally.

You should instead be updating the `next` field of the last object within your linked list.

Your code should look something like this

```
  else{ // not the first node
    ListNode<E> temp = head;
    while(temp.next != null){ // find the last node
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    // create new node to be added to linked list
    ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>();
    newNode.data = e;
    newNode.next = null;

    // set the previous last node to the new, created node
    temp.next = newNode;

    size++; //increment size of the LinkedList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has everything to do with your adding.

Look carefully at the `else` block in your `add()` method. You create a new node but you never attach it to the end of your list: you don't make any existing node's `next` field point at your new node.

```
else{ // not the first node
    ListNode<E> temp = head;
    while(temp != null){ // you actually go one past the last node
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    // at this point temp points to null, not to the last node

    ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>();
    newNode.data = e;
    newNode.next = null;

    temp = newNode;
    // temp used to point to null, now it points to your new node,
    // but it doesn't make newNode a part of your list

    size++;
}
```

Because of that your list will never contain more than 1 element, since you basically throw away anything passed to your `add()` method, except for the first call, where you set your `head`.

Here's one way you could change this `else` block for addition to work:

```
else{
    ListNode<E> temp = head;
    while(temp.next != null){ // find the last node (the one that has no next)
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    // now temp points to the last node in the list so far

    ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>();
    newNode.data = e;
    newNode.next = null;

    temp.next = newNode;
    // now the last node's next points to your new node,
    // so it's now a part of your list

    size++;
}
```